# Debug trait implementation with newline characters

Tags: rust

Given the following program:

```
use std::fmt;

struct A;

impl fmt::Debug for A {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        format!("\nA\n").fmt(f)
    }
} 

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", A);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
"\nA\n"
```

Is it somehow possible to get these newline characters "translated" into real newline characters? Unfortunately I can't use the `Display` trait as this is for use with [hamcrest-rust](https://github.com/carllerche/hamcrest-rust) which uses the `Debug` trait when showing error messages.

Comment: The `fmt` you called was `Debug::fmt` on `String`, which escapes special characters like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using the [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format!.html) use the [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write!.html) macro. From looking at the documentation, `write!` writes directly onto the buffer, while `format!` creates a `String`, and formats the arguments into `fmt::Debug` which automatically escapes special characters.

```
use std::fmt;

struct A;

impl fmt::Debug for A {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "\nA\n")
    }
} 

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", A);
}
```

Comment: Strings do not automatically escape characters.

Comment: @Shepmaster Updated to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

[Bluss's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874499/debug-trait-implementation-with-newline-characters#comment53582364_32874499) is the real solution to your mystery:

```
use std::fmt;

struct A;

impl fmt::Debug for A {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Display::fmt(&format!("\nA\n"), f)
    }
} 

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", A);
}
```

Of course, the answer with `write!` is simpler in the end run, but it doesn't explain why you had the problem you did.